# Do polynomials have a limit ratio of 1 over fixed intervals?

Tags: limits, polynomials, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

If $p$ is an increasing polynomial function, and $c>0$ is a constant, do we always have:
$$ \underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}  \dfrac{p(xc+c)}{p(xc)} = 1?$$

I think if I am not missing anything, as the coefficient and degree of the leading terms will be equal in the numerator and denominator, by L'Hôspital's rule the limit should be equal to $1$. I am wondering if there is an easier proof for this fact, or anything that I am missing.

Comment: you should start with $t= xc$ and $P(t+c_1)/ P(t) $

Comment: Thank you @WillJagy ! I agree it is nicer to first substitute $t$ and then take the limit over $t$.

Comment: Alt. hint: if $p$ has degree $n\ge 1$ then $p(t+c)-p(t) = r(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$. Then $p(t+c)/p(t) = 1+r(t)/p(t)$ where the second term has limit $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need L'Hopital's Rule to prove this. If$$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0,$$with $N\in\Bbb N$ and $a_n\ne0$, then\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(xc+c)}{p(xc)}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p\bigl((x+1)c\bigr)}{p(xc)}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_n\bigl((x+1)c\bigr)^n+a_{n-1}\bigl((x+1)c\bigr)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\bigl((x+1)c\bigr)+a_0}{a_n(xc)^n+a_{n-1}(xc)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(xc)+a_0}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_nc^nx^n+\text{terms of smaller degree}}{a_nc^nx^n+\text{terms of smaller degree}}\end{align}and this limit is equal to $1$; just divide both the numerator and the denominator by $x^n$. Then it's clear that the limit is $\frac{a_nc^n}{a_nc^n}=1$.

Comment: To be clearer (pedagogically), I'd suggest explicitly stating that the final fraction is referring to terms of smaller degree in $x$.  And I'd just divide by $x^n$ to avoid having to note that neither $a_n$ nor $c$ can be $0$.

Comment: @RobertShore I have edited my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for this answer! Is it correct that we did not assume $p$ is increasing? And can we use the small-oh notation for "terms of small degree", e.g., $o(x^n)$?

Comment: Indeed , I made no assumption about whether or not $p(x)$ is increasing. And, yes, it is correct to use $o(x^n)$ instead of “terms of smaller degree”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you! Because small-oh notation has some absolute value in the definition I was confused, but this is very clear. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's an easier proof.  Divide the numerator and denominator of the fraction by $x^n$, where $n = \deg p$.  Then your numerator and denominator both end up as $a_nc^n$ (where $a_n$ is the coefficient of the $x^n$ term of your polynomial) plus a bunch of terms that go to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.  By the definition of degree, $a_n \neq 0$, and you're given that $c \neq 0$ (in fact, $c \gt 0$), so this fraction goes to $1$.

Answer (score 4):

It is true what you say. Recall that if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are two polynomials of the same degree, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$, with $a_n$ and $b_n$ being the leading coefficients of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, respectively.

In the case we are considering, the two polynomials have the same degree and $a_n=kc^n=b_n$, where $k$ is the principal coefficient of $p$. Therefore,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{p(xc+c)}{p(xc)}=\dfrac{kc^n}{kc^n}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial can be written as: $$a(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\dots (x-\lambda_n)$$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\dots\lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$

The leading coeficient $a$ factors out of the ratio, which "distributes" over the sub-polynomials, so it is sufficient to prove
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{p(xc+c)}{p(xc)}=1$$
for $p(x) = (x-\lambda_{k})$ . We get $\frac{xc +  c-\lambda_{k}}{xc-\lambda_{k}} = 1 + \frac{c}{xc-\lambda_{k}} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that for any non zero polynomial with degree $n$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{p(x)}{x^n}=a_n$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{p(xc+c)}{p(xc)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{p(xc+c)}{(xc+c)^n}\frac{(xc)^n}{p(xc)}\frac{(xc+c)^n}{x^n}\frac{x^n}{(xc)^n}=\frac{a_nc^n}{a_nc^n}=1$$